# How to merge both dataframes by fixed columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I got a problem when trying to merge two dataframes in R and I need your help. 
Suppose that I have following dataframes:

```
> Data_A
Code    year    score   
A       1991    1   
A       1992    2   
A       1993    3   
B       1991    3   
B       1993    7   
> Data_B
Code    year    l.score 
A       1991    NA  
A       1992    1   
A       1993    2   
A       1994    3   
B       1991    NA  
B       1992    3
B       1993    NA  
B       1994    7
```

And the desire result after merging them should be like that:

```
> Data_merge
    Code    year    score   l.score
    A      1991     1       NA
    A      1992     2       1
    A      1993     3       2
    B      1991     3       NA
    B      1993     7       NA
```

It means that when merging these dataframes, share columns in one will be kept (in this case, "Code" and "year" of Data_A). I tried `merge(Data_A, Data_B, all = FALSE)` but not success. Someone have any idea? Thanks for reading!

Comment: `merge(Data_A, Data_B)` works for me...Note tha `all = FALSE` is the default so no need to specify it unless it is `TRUE`

Comment: In reality, Data_A has 8291 observations and Data_B has 8299 observations. I used `Data_C<-merge(Data_A, Data_B)` and Data_C has 8809 observations. But, as I mention above, it should have 8291 observations (= Data_A).

Comment: You probably have duplicate entries

Comment: @sindri_baldur I tried them, but it does not work. I do not know why. Thanks.

Comment: @Sotos Could you give me some advices?

Comment: I thought I just did :) Look for duplicate entries of `Code` and `Year`. Something like `duplicated(Data_A[,1:2])`...Same with `Data_B`

Comment: I still confuse it, but will try your suggest. Thanks @Sotos

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
    Data_A %>%
    left_join(Data_B, by = c('Code', 'year'))

  Code year score l.score
1    A 1991     1      NA
2    A 1992     2       1
3    A 1993     3       2
4    B 1991     3      NA
5    B 1993     7      NA
```

Comment: You mean `c("Code","year")`, right? I tried your code but the result is the same with `merge()`.

Comment: It should work with `c('Code', 'year')` as well. It returns the output you stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks @AlexB. I found the problem. It comes from my dataset. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your own solution can work (I am using `R 3.6.1`), but no idea why you cannot

```
> merge(Data_A, Data_B, all = FALSE)
  Code year score X1.score
1    A 1991     1       NA
2    A 1992     2        1
3    A 1993     3        2
4    B 1991     3       NA
5    B 1993     7       NA
```

**DATA**

```
Data_A <- structure(list(Code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), year = c(1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1991L, 
1993L), score = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

Data_B <- structure(list(Code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), year = c(1991L, 
1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L), X1.score = c(NA, 
1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: I am also using R 3.6.1 but it does not work with me :(. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @VĩnhVũQuang I am not sure if the data frames `Data_A` and `Data_B` are the same as yours ( see the `DATA` part). Maybe you can have a look at it, e.g., trying my `dput()` DATA to your code to see if it works

Comment: I also think that my data have problem. I will try again. Thanks!